# How can I include a parameter in a tcolorbox style?

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a `tcolorbox` style that I wish to use among several of my boxes, however I want to be able to customize the color scheme each box uses without creating a new style. For example, this is what I have now:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{blue-labeled/.style={
  colframe=blue,
  colback=blue!20,
  boxed title style={
    colback=blue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{theorem}{
  blue-labeled,
  title=Theorem:,
}
```

However, if I wish to add another box with a green background:

```latex
\tcbset{blue-labeled/.style={
  colframe=green,
  colback=green!20,
  boxed title style={
    colback=green,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{idea}{
  green-labeled,
  title=Idea:,
}
```

I would need to make another style that's green which feels extremely redundant to me.

Before anyone suggests it, I do *not* want to simply move the color scheme to my `tcolorbox` definition and having the color act as a parameter there. This is for a large project I am working on where there are numerous types of boxes that all rely on the same overall layout, but otherwise are defined very differently. I also want it to be flexible enough such that I can experiment with different colours quickly without having to edit numerous lines.

Right now the only solution that allows the flexibility (but code becomes a lot more redundant) is if I have several style definitions `blue-labeled`, `green-labeled`, `red-labeled` e.g. and then to change the colour scheme I would just have to modify one word.

What is a quick way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE.

## Simpler way

A `tcolorbox` style, or more generally a `pgfkeys` style, takes arguments. You can put this to good use here.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  my box/.style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=#1,
    colback=#1!20,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.2cm, yshift=-0.2cm},
    boxed title style={
      colback=#1,
      outer arc=0pt,
      arc=0pt,
      top=3pt,
      bottom=3pt,
    },
  },
}

\newtcolorbox{theorem}[1][]{
  my box=blue,
  title=Theorem,
  #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{idea}[1][]{
  my box=green,
  title=Idea,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  This is blue.
\end{theorem}

\begin{idea}
  This is green.
\end{idea}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## More flexible way

You can interpret an argument as a style that defines other styles. In this case, this allows us to define two keyword arguments, one for the style options for the main box (`main`), the other one for the boxed title (`title`). For instance, the first box type in the following example uses this:

```latex
my box={
  main={colframe=blue!40, colback=blue!20},
  title={colback=blue!60!black},
},
```

I also defined an `append main` (resp. `append title`) style in case you want to *add* to the `main style` (resp. `title style`) instead of overriding it. Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  % Defaults
  my box/main style/.style={},
  my box/title style/.style={},
  % Use the 'append' variants if you want to add to the defaults instead of
  % overriding them.
  my box/main/.style={/tcb/my box/main style/.style={#1}},
  my box/title/.style={/tcb/my box/title style/.style={#1}},
  my box/append main/.style={/tcb/my box/main style/.append style={#1}},
  my box/append title/.style={/tcb/my box/title style/.append style={#1}},
  %
  my box/.style={
    my box/.cd, #1,
    /tcb/.cd,
    enhanced,
    my box/main style,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.2cm, yshift=-0.2cm},
    boxed title style={
      outer arc=0pt,
      arc=0pt,
      top=3pt,
      bottom=3pt,
      my box/title style,
      },
  },
}

\newtcolorbox{theorem}[1][]{
  my box={
    main={colframe=blue!40, colback=blue!20},
    title={colback=blue!60!black},
  },
  title=Theorem,
  #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{idea}[1][]{
  my box={
    main={colframe=orange, colback=green!40!cyan},
    title={colback=blue!60, colframe=gray},
  },
  title=Idea,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  This is blue.
\end{theorem}

\begin{idea}
  This has various colors.
\end{idea}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, please see the latest version of this answer. In the second example, there was a naming clash that made the code confusing and prevented the defaults from being effective. This is now fixed and I added `append main` and `append title` styles for convenience. I found the naming clash because someone had the nice idea to upvote this answer today, so I reread it and noticed the problem. Thanks to this kind anonymous! :-)

Comment: Your answer made me understand the arguments in pgfkeys.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb That's nice to hear. Now you may want to look at the Ti*k*Z & PGF manual to see the variants of `.style`, especially `.style 2 args`, `.style n args` and `.style args` (at first, I was surprised that different syntax was needed depending on the number of arguments).